# org.springframework.cloud cannot be resolved when import EnableDiscoveryClient for registering service with Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

In my spring-boot project, I try to register my project as eureka discovery client. This is my simple code:

```
package com.my.simpleService;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

// Compiler error: org.springframework.cloud cannot be resolved
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I get compiler error: `import org.springframework.cloud cannot be resolved`.

Following is my gradle.build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.my.simpleService'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'


configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', '2020.0.0')
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:3.0.3'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Why I get that compiler error? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `spring-cloud-commons`, e.g. update your dependencies to the following:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do I have redundant dependency from what you see? Since I have googled and added several dependencies try to solve the issue. For example is that `mavenBom` needed?

Comment: Hmm... I still get the same error on my SringToolSuite

Comment: The `mavenBom` is what defines the versions of many other dependencies so it should remain. This works because it is used by the `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you execute Gradle from the command line, e.g. `gradle build`?

Comment: Perhaps another `org.springframework.cloud` dependency is missing? The `EnableDiscoveryClient` is located in the `spring-cloud-commons` as shown here: https://search.maven.org/search?q=c:EnableDiscoveryClient%20v:3.0.3  , but perhaps you have added some other class elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, on my IDE, I clicked on "Gradle Tasks" and double clicked "build". Same compiler error.

Comment: I don't have other classes. I just started the project. What you see here is all what I have in Java code.

Comment: Did you save the `gradle.build` after you changed it? Do you see the same error if you open a terminal in the project root folder and execute `gradle build`?

Comment: Get build error ` Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-cloud-commons:3.0.3`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The correct dependency should be `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons`. I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Yep, I noticed & updated. But my IDE still gives the same error. On terminal when run `gradle build` it gives a different error, at the step of `> Task :test`.

Comment: I wonder how to make my STS IDE stop showing me the same error... Tried restarting the STS, doesn't help...

Comment: It turned out the problme is the STS IDE is not smart enough. After I switched to IntelliJ , no such issue. I will dump my STS IDE.